# Chrome and Firefox behave odd, switching to first tab, zooming on Google Maps

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I suddenly got odd problem with my browsers. After opening a link (nothing bogus, blog about energy prices, found on major Reddit sub, nobody else reported issues) my Chrome browser started to always switch to first tab. If I open new tab, Chrome will switch to first one. If I click on last one it will quickly tabulate through them to the first one. If I move first somewhere else it will tab to new first. Both FF and Chrome have issues on Google Maps, they zoom out on the map to maximum. FF however do not seems to have switching to first tab issue.

I tried reinstalling Chrome but it did not helped.

Any suggestions?

thanks

-Mat

P.S. I am on 22.04

Comment: deb package or snap?

Comment: deb for Chrome. Firefox came bundled.

Comment: Could your keyboard or mouse be firing? Looks like the arrow buttons are stuck....

Comment: No. If it would be keyboard I could not type this reply most likely. Mouse cursor also do not "run away", beside tested with 3 mouses.